# Determinando hora em que função será executada

Tags: javascript, funções, timer

Exemplo:

```
var horaAtual = new Date();

var horaInicio = new Date("Fri Apr 01 2016 23:30:00");

//Quando(horaAtual == horaInicio)
//execute algo...
```

Quero que uma função seja executada quando atinja uma hora já determinada no meu código, isso sem que o usuário precise ficar atualizando a página.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
var specificTime = new Date('Fri Apr 01 2016 23:39:49').getTime();
var nowTime = new Date().getTime();

if (specificTime > nowTime) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    alert('It is time!')
  }, specificTime - nowTime)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpns7cup/

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz por ter ajudado @Naldson , espero que tenha estudado o código para entender como funciona. Estudar pequenos detalhes lhe tornam um grande programador!

Abrs e bons estudos!

Comment: Muito obrigado, @Willy

Answer (score 3):

A função que faz isto é a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

```js
var horaInicio = new Date("Fri Apr 01 2016 23:55:00") - new Date();
setTimeout(function(){ alert("teste" )}, horaInicio);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Browser/TimeoutSpecificTime.js).

Comment: Olá, @bigown Eu tentei fazer assim : https://codeshare.io/LQUun . Mas assim que eu atualizo a página, o alert já é exibido.... O que poderia ser?

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de tirar o horário atual.